# Modal window overlay persists after closing Lightbox

Tags: javascript, html, popup, hide

I have a main page that has a popup (please see window number 1 in the image I added). In this popup, there is a button of `skip`. if the user presses `skip` button, the popup is gone (and then, the user sees the main page) (window number 3). **but** if the user doesn't press on the popup, but the main window, the color of the main window becomes to a gray color (window number 2). if I press the main window about 3 times, then the color will be changed into a white color (window number 3).

[image]

I think I have to hide my popup if the user presses the main window instead of the popup.

how can I fix it?

my popup is called: `class="popup_window"`. the `X` and the `SKIP` buttons are called: `btn_x` and `btn_skip`.

any help appreciated!

**UPDATE** this is my welcome_msg java script code:

```
// welcome message
$("#welcome_dialog").lightbox_me({
 centered: true,
 onLoad: function() {
    //alert("Page is loaded");
}
});
```

Comment: Show your code. Are you using a Javascript library to implement the popup?

Comment: please wait.. I am updating my topic..

Comment: Dude, don't make me Google! I believe you're using the Lightbox_me jQuery plugin (http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/), yes?

Comment: is this the plugin you are using? http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/

Comment: yes, it is (and I'm sorry).

Comment: Well, clicking the overlay (i.e. the main window as you call it) should dismiss the lightbox (see the "closeClick" property) unless you have this set to false as a default somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just looked at the lightbox_me plugin website and on the homepage it lists the possible options you can use. You need to add the following to your code: "closeClick : true".

So the code you posted above would look like this:

```
$("#welcome_dialog").lightbox_me({
  centered: true,
  closeClick: true,
  onLoad: function() {
  //alert("Page is loaded");
 }
 });
```

As described on the site:

```
CloseClick  true    Whether or not to close the lightbox with the user clicks the overlay.
```

Source: http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/